# Guidance on reopening a closed question

Tags: discussion

About https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718879/lamports-bakery-algorithm-in-java

I have additional questions on this thread: should I reopen it or create a new one?
Just to give you an idea of the kind of questions I have:

1. The Java code mentioned in the thread (taken from Wikipedia) uses atomic operations (AtomicIntegerArray) the usage of which is in sharp contrast with the idea of the algorithm itself  (which is to replace atomic operations in the first place).
2. I would like to post a Java implementation (not working for me) in order to get help on why it does not work.

Is it better to reopen the question by editing the OP question (and if so, should I quote the OP question or just replace its content?) or to create a new question altogether?

Comment: There are no "threads", Stack Overflow is not a forum. If you have a different question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That question has been closed as it isn't suitable for Stack Overflow. It shouldn't be reopened

If you have any follow on questions from reading it, you should ask them as separate questions (one question per post - don't ask a few questions in one post), but make sure they are on-topic and suitable (see our [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Your first question isn't a question - it is a statement. If you are looking for discussion, then Stack Overflow is not the place to have that discussion. If you have a question about a specific bit of code, you should include that and ask about it.

The second question seems to ask us to debug your code for you - that's not suitable either. If you have a problem with your code, post the *relevant* bits of code, explain what you tried and what exactly isn't working - [see our asking a good question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried  your links and they are no longer valid. Thought you should know.

Comment: @WJS - thanks, looks like someone changed the path to those pages, but didn't consider that a lot of posts were linked to them.

Comment: @Oded SO has closed my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724424/guidelines-broken-i-dont-understand-this-java-class-declaration and another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71726495/java-coding-style-to-be-more-concise that are 1. a bit of code, 2. on topic and suitable. StacOverflow policies are not very fair on downvoting

Comment: How can I undelete a downvoted off-topic question? If it is offtopic, if I edit it 1 thousand times it will be forever offtopic. The result is that I cannot ask new questions. It is not fair. The question will be deleted without any punishment, amen. Another thing: why downvote for non-english users? on the planet there are 6 billions of people who can't talk english very well